# Will 0.5 volts overvoltage damage a LED monitor?

Tags: led, display

I have a brand new LG LED monitor but for reasons which I won't detail here, I would like to run it with 19.5 volts instead of the 19 volts it is rated for (it came with a power supply of 19 volts). Am I risking damage by doing this, i.e. would the 0.5 volt difference be within the safe zone?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Very probably not, but maybe, who knows. Add a diode in series if you a really worried.

Comment: +1 for @WesleyLee ... beat me to the diode suggestion! Seriously, find a diode with about a 0.3-0.4V knee voltage & you should be right at 19V to the monitor once it starts drawing full current ;)

Comment: Thank you guys, actually it's not an engineering project, just some unusual life circumstances that need me to run it this way for a few days, so I'm just wondering what my chances are of ruining my monitor by doing it.

Comment: Come on Marco ... use the intended power supply for the LED monitor and stop futzing around.

Comment: @Michael Karas Thanks but did it occur to you maybe that's physically not an option for me write now, otherwise why would I bother to post here. Maybe I'm on a research station in Antarctica, or in the Canadian wilderness, so don't assume.

Comment: Almost certainly safe. YMMV but probably not. Long wires or small resistor would allow the slight drop neeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking at running the monitor from 19.5 V instead of 19 V.

Unless of its input stage voltage is unlikely to be tighter than the 2.6 % increase you're planning to supply it with. But your 19.5 V supply will have an output tolerance too so it's the maximum that supply might output that you have to consider.

If it's not marked, let's give the example of a 19.5 V +/- 10 % supply. That could produce 21.45 V, which is means your monitor's power input tolerance would have to be 12.9 %.

In truth, I would expect it to be fine as an input stage drive by a power adaptor with a long lead will be designed for wider tolerance, both up and down.

(If you have the tolerances for the power supply and monitor specs, revise your question and I can revise this answer further. Please don't just post the model numbers and expect us to find them for you, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Your row drivers and column drivers will merely switch a bit faster, and perhaps ring a bit longer before they settle.

Aim a tiny fan into the incoming--air vent holes (at the bottom) and double the life.

Comment: I've designed this systems.

Answer (score 0):

It will almost certainly be fine, especially if it's only for a few days.  You'll just pushing some components slightly closer to their ratings.